# Android. Замена фрагметов через replace

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Не происходит замена фрагмента по ниже указаному коду. Подскажите что я упустил. Заранние спасибо.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private FragmentWelcom fragmentWallcome;
    private FragmentWeater fragmentWeater;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        fragmentLogin    = new FragmentLogin();
        fragmentWallcome = new FragmentWelcom();
        fragmentWeater   = new FragmentWeater();

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
}

 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.contact_item:
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentWallcome);
                    return true;
            case R.id.weater_item:
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentWeater);
                return true;
            default:

                break;
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После `fragmentTransaction.replace(...);` добавьте `fragmentTransaction.commit();` и вызывайте `fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();` в каждом `case`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private FragmentWelcom fragmentWallcome;
    private FragmentWeater fragmentWeater;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        fragmentLogin    = new FragmentLogin();
        fragmentWallcome = new FragmentWelcom();
        fragmentWeater   = new FragmentWeater();

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
}

 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.contact_item:
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentWallcome);
                fragmentManager.commit();
                    return true;
            case R.id.weater_item:
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentWeater);
                fragmentManager.commit();
                return true;
            default:

                break;
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Почиму то приложения падает с ошибкой FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called

Comment: @Fedia обновил ответ